# How to setup home page / which is coming from Drupal as /home in Gatsby

Tags: drupal, gatsby

I am creating a Gatsby website using Drupal CMS as backend. I have landing page content type in Drupal which is providing the home page and about us pages. Now Drupal home page path is /home. But Gatsby has home page URL '/'. After pull data from Drupal then Gatsby considers /home as separate page not as index page.

I tried to set the path in CreatePage API on Gatsby node js file. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Hers is my found,

- Delete the index.js file in Gatsby
- Make sure Drupal home page as URL
  alias as /home.
- Go to Gatsby-node.js file and change the slug into '/'
  from '/home/' before calling CreatePage like below
- **Note: Context slug should remain /home/ so don't change the value.**

```html
  result.data.allNodeLanding.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    const slug = node.fields.slug;
    if (node.fields.slug === '/home/') {
      node.fields.slug = '/'
    }
    actions.createPage({
      path: node.fields.slug,
      component: tpl,
      context: {
        slug: slug
      }
    });
  });
```